# PHP foreach WordPress get parent category name and slug

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I am working on a function that produces custom breadcrumbs for a particular set of categories.

category slugs are stored in an array() as follows.

```
$specialCatsLvl2 = array('base-ball', 'soc-cer', 'foot-ball', 'hockey', 'basket-ball')  
// lets pretend these are the real slugs
```

I want to write a foreach() {} loop so I can get the parent category, and then use that parent category and slug as variables in a link in the breadcrumbs.

This is was I have.

```
if (is_product_category($specialCatsLvl2)) {

    foreach ($specialCatsLvl2 as $cat) {
    $parent = get_category($cat->category_parent);
    $parent_name = $parent->cat_name;
    }

echo $shop_link . $delimiter . '<a href="' . home_url() . '/product-category/' . $parent_name->slug . '/">' . $parent_name . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . single_cat_title('', false) . $current_after; 

}
```

Is this the right way to get the parent-product category?

Any input or advice on this matter would be really helpful, I feel like I have searched and searched about made no progress for four hours.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to link to every parent category of categories in `$specialCatsLvl2`?

Comment: Sorry to be so confusing. Yes. I need to get the parent-slug & name foreach of the categories in the array. 
So for every category in the array I to link to its specific parent category. 
does that clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure to get this right. Let's say I'm in the "Soccer shoes" category, which would be a category child of "Soccer", you want to have a breadcrumb like "Home > Soccer > Soccer shoes"? But only if the parent category of "Soccer shoes" is one of the category in `$specialCatsLvl2` ?

Comment: in the above example soccer-shoes whould be the category listed in the array, and soccer would be link i am trying to generate.

Answer (score 1):

There is few errors in your code. First, this: `$parent_name->slug` will not work. `$parent_name` is a string, you should use `$parent->slug` instead. Secondly, you send an array of slug to WooCommerce [`is_product_category`](http://is_product_category) function, which expect a string, not an array. Thirdly, `$cat->category_parent` will not work, as `$cat` is a string, and not a category object. Fourth, at every iteration of your loop `$parent` and `$parent_name` are overriden.

I would suggest this code instead, that will write a breadcrumb like this with your example array (assuming Sports is the parent category of Soccer):

> Home > Sports > Soccer

```
// Print the breadcrumb base
echo $shop_link . ' ' . $delimiter;

// If we're in a category that match your array
$current_category = get_category (get_query_var('cat'));
if(in_array($current_category->slug, $specialCatsLvl2) && $current_category->parent) {
    $parent = get_category($current_category->parent);
    // Print the parent category link
    echo '<a href="' . home_url() . '/product-category/' . $parent->slug .'/">' . $parent->name . '</a> ' . $delimiter;
}

 // Print the current category name
echo $delimiter . $current_before . single_cat_title('', false) . $current_after;
```

Comment: Thank you for working with me on this. 

I have implemented this code. However it looks like it is only echo-ing the last line, so I don't think that the `in_array` portion of the code is returning `true` because the category link is not being printed.

Comment: Could you do some `var_dump` in order to see the `$current_category->slug` and `$current_category->parent` values?